# I am trying to make typewriter effect in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am trying to make typewriter in js

```
private i: number = 0;
  private text: string = "hello stack";
  private timer: number = 50;
  typeWriter() {
    console.log(this.text.length);
    console.log(this.i);
    if (this.i < this.text.length) {
      document.querySelector(".quotes").innerHTML += this.text[0];
      this.i++;
      setTimeout(this.typeWriter, this.timer);
    }
  }
```

something like this but after printing h or after the first call it gives me error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. And the value of i is also not updated.

Answer (score 3):

You either need to use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) or arrow function notation to refer to the class member variables using `this` keyword in callbacks. If not, the `this` keyword refers to the scope of the function.

Try the following

```js
typeWriter() {
  console.log(this.text.length);
  console.log(this.i);
  if (this.i < this.text.length) {
    document.querySelector(".quotes").innerHTML += this.text[0];
    this.i++;
    setTimeout(this.typeWriter.bind(this), this.timer);
  }
}
```

**OR**

```js
typeWriter() {
  console.log(this.text.length);
  console.log(this.i);
  if (this.i < this.text.length) {
    document.querySelector(".quotes").innerHTML += this.text[0];
    this.i++;
    setTimeout(() => this.typeWriter(), this.timer);
  }
}
```

Also, shouldn't `this.text[0]` be `this.text[this.i]`? Furthermore, it's better not to access the DOM directly while using Angular. You could instead try to use Angular [Renderer](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).